# Incorrect decrement warning from Xcode from my class method

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, memory-management

I created a class to take care of my UILabels in 1 line instead of taking 4-5 by doing...

```
+(UILabel*)BeautifyLabel:(UILabel *)label withText:(NSString *)message withFont:(NSString *)font andSize:(float)size andColor:(UIColor *)theColor{
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.textColor = theColor;
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:font size:size];
    label.text = message;
    return label;
}
```

And to call it, i do

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake....];
label = [CommonMethods BeautifyLabel:label withText:@"hi" withFont:@"Helvetica" andSize:13 andColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[self.view addSubview label];
[label release];
```

The analyzer probably doesn't like the part where I pass the label to my CommomMethods class, but since i'm initializing and releases the label in the current controller and the CommonMethods class doesn't do anything memory related, this is safe, right?

Also, would this be cause for Apple to reject my app?

Thanks

Comment: Why should apple reject?

Comment: What's the text of the analyzer error?  And what line does it complain about?

Comment: "Incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not owned at this point by the caller" and it shows the warning at the `[label release]` line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your BeautifyLabel method should not return the label pointer.  That is probably what the analyzer is complaining about (but it would be nice to see the text of the analyzer error).

The analyzer is assuming that BeautifyLabel method is returning a new instance of the label which then overwrites the one you had in label variable thus causing a memory leak of the overwritten instance (and overreleasing of the returned instance).

Comment: The text from the analyzer is "Incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not owned at this point by the caller".  But since i'm doing any init,copy, retain, or release in my class method, there is no leak or overreleasing, right?

Comment: @AndrewPark - The static analyzer doesn't actually run the code, so it doesn't really know if everything works out ok in the end - it checks to see if you follow the guidelines, and this code definitely does not.

Comment: Ah thanks.  I changed the class method so that the label was initialized within it, then i autorelease it before returning it.

Answer (score 0):

In the code:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake....];
label = [CommonMethods BeautifyLabel:label withText:@"hi" withFont:@"Helvetica" andSize:13 andColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

`label` is allocated on the first line, on the second line `label` is **replaed** by the call to `BeautifyLabel` or so the analyzer thinks, not knowing what is done in `BeautifyLabel`. It can't assume you are returning the same object.

Either do not make the assignment:

```
[CommonMethods BeautifyLabel:label withText:@"hi" withFont:@"Helvetica" andSize:13 andColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

or use different label pointer names:

```
UILabel *labelTemp = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake....];
label = [CommonMethods BeautifyLabel:labelTemp withText:@"hi" withFont:@"Helvetica" andSize:13 andColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```